# Use Bluetooth to transfer gyroscope data to another computer

Tags: java, android, c++, bluetooth

I want to do a simple project where I send the phone's gyroscope data to a computer, where both are connected over Bluetooth. The receiving computer will be using C++, which I assume has its own Bluetooth communication protocols.

I have no idea how to get started - does anyone have sample code or tutorials for this? Preferably for both the client (phone) and the server (computer).

Comment: first cut of your project in smaller parts where you can do a quicker proof of concept.  Then combine the parts.  Ask more specific questions about issues you encounter while actually working on the parts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the SPP BT profile to continuously sending data over bluetooth.
You can see a SPP link over BT as an normal RS232 serial cable.

Here are a sample code how to create an app (bluetooth chat) in android using the spp profile. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

On the computer side, are you using windows? 
If so, the bluetooth stack on computer will create an COM port for you with the SPP data from phone. 
I haven't create any application that read and write from a COM port in windows but I guess it will be tutorials on the net. 
First step could be to connect an Hyper terminal to that COM port and see that you can read data from it.